# Свернуть меню при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть меню/навигация: [codepen](https://codepen.io/dis6/pen/OJVRZOq)

Я добавил кусок кода jquery, чтобы меню сворачивалось при клике на ссылку:

```
(function(){
        var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
                header = document.querySelector('.header');

        burger.onclick = function() {
                header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
        }
    }());

 $('.menu-item').on('click', function () {
      $('.header').removeClass('menu-opened');
    });
```

Однако, меня смущает корректность кода в таком виде несмотря на то, что всё работает.
Скажите пожалуйста, корректно ли использовать такое сочетание, и по возможности помогите с более корректным вариантом скрипта.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codepen.io/romzes2/pen/OJVREYp

```
$('div.burger-container, .menu-item').on('click', function () {
    $('.header').toggleClass('menu-opened');
});
```